# key generation in RSA cryptosystem: why it can be performed in polynomial time?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, cryptography

Suppose that I want to generate the keys of the RSA cryptosystem: the public key will be the couple $(n,e)$ where $n$ is the product of two primes $p$ and $q$  and gcd$(\phi(n),e)=1$.The private key will be the integer $d$ such that $ed=1$ (mod $\phi(n)$). Suppose that the length of $n$ (represented as bit string) is $k$, therefore the following is an algorithm that outputs $n$, $e$ and $d$:

1. Choose two very large random prime integers:
   $p$ and $q$ such that $|pq|_2=k$
2. Compute $n$ and $φ(n)$:
   $n = pq$ and $φ(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$
3. Choose an integer $e$, $1 < e < φ(n)$ such that:
   gcd$(e, φ(n)) = 1$
4. Compute $d$, $1 < d < φ(n)$ such that:
   $ed ≡ 1$ (mod $φ(n)$)

I have showed that points 1,2,4 can be computed in polynomial time of $k$, but I can't find any algorithm that can compute the point 3 in polynomial time.

Do you have any idea about it?

**Edit:** I'm  wrong about the fact that the point $1$ can be performed in polynomial time. I had in my mind a wrong brute force argument.  In an answer above, the user @TonyK says that this is an open problem.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 is the hard one! I think that it still hasn't been proven to be polynomial, although it is believed to be.

Step 3 is easy, if all you need is an $e$ such that $(e,\phi(n)) = 1$ (although a real-life public key protocol will require more than this). Just let $e$ be the smallest prime that doesn't divide $\phi(n)$. This is clearly polynomial in $\log_2(n)$.

Comment: But I believe OP wants it polynomial in $\log_2(n)$, as $k$ is the length of $n$  I think it still works.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Yes, thank you. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: For point 1 I can for example try a brute force argument to sieve two primes of length $\frac{k}{2}$.

Comment: Damn! it doesn't work I need to do about $\frac{1}{2}2^{\frac{k}{2}}$ primality tests so an exponential number.

Comment: For 1, I believe you can use the prime number theorem, at least in practice.  The density of primes around $2^{\frac k2}$ is $1$ in $\ln 2^{\frac k2}=\frac k2 \ln 2$, then a few Fermat tests and call it good.  This is polynomial in $k$.  Of course, worst case is worse.

Comment: @RossMillikan: "at least in practice". Exactly! This was the subject of [one of the Polymath projects](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3956), which failed to crack the problem. Without assuming any unproven conjectures, prime generation can't be claimed to be polynomial-time.

Answer (score 1):

The [primorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) grow as $m^m$, so less than $k$ of them will be less than $n$.  At least one of the first $k+1$ primes will not divide $\phi(n)$  Can you sieve the first $k$ primes in polynomial time?

Comment: Polynomial time respect to what? respect to $k$ or the length of $k$ as bit string?

Comment: I thought $k$ was the length of the bit string, about $\log_2(n)$.  So it should be polynomial in $k$